# Is there a way in PHP to capture ALL the information passed using the POST method

Tags: php, post, get, http-post

A little while ago, I asked a question about using the same input name/hidden name multiple times in a page, and got an answer that did not work as it suggested the I had to use to put brackets after the field name, like `partno[]`.

I cannot use this in my form, as the cart it is being sent to only recognizes certain field names like: partno, item, price, qty, etc. (I cannot use `partno[], item[]`, etc.)  So I really need to be able to get all the values for each identical field name used multiple times.  When I use the method `GET`, it will display all the values for each field name used in the address bar.  You can try [this](http://wcoins.com/brenckles2/) and submit the form.  Look at the url in the address bar.

My new question is: Is there a way in PHP to capture all the information passed using the `POST` method? (like what shows up in the address bar in the example above but using `POST`, not `GET`).  I can parse it if I can figure out a way to capture it.

Thanks,
Kelly

Comment: just use `method="post"` in your form?

Comment: @harakiri op uses the same parameters multiple times, 5x PartNo etc. as you could see in his sample url. This won't work with get nor post. you still need a unique name per input.

Comment: This limitation and the `name="brackets[]"` syntax is purely a PHP thing, it's totally legit to have multiple inputs with the same name.

Comment: maybe i'm missing the point, but PHP joins $_GET and $_POST in a global variable called $_REQUEST. I'm using this thing only for years (?) and never thought of get/post again

Comment: I'm just realizing that this is indeed a very good question !

Answer (score 2):

You just use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

So if you were using get in the following way:

```
?something=somevalue
```

And were catching it with `$_GET['something']`, you would now use `$_POST['something']`.

Comment: I believe that the point of the OP's question was accessing the values of fields with identical names, wihout using bracket notation like `name="items[]"`, Switching from post/get won't make a difference. The OP is already asking how to do this with `POST`, so I can't see what this answer is for. I know there is a tendency to answer the question title rather than read the whole thing.

Comment: My answer doesn't have him using `names="items[]"` format. You obviously don't fully understand the original method he was trying, as it completely differs from the answer I provided. I'm pretty sure he was the first up vote for my answer too, so yeah.

Comment: Carefully reread the question (also, new users cannot upvote until they reach 15 rep, and from the profile I see 0 votes cast).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the untainted data directly from the input stream:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

So if you have something like this:

```
<input name="type" value="val1">
<input name="type" value="val2">
<input name="type" value="val3">
```

You will get a string like this:

```
type=val1&type=val2&type=val3
```

You can then parse this string into an array and create your own "raw post data".

> http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php
>
> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
> from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
> to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
> depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
> $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
> less memory intensive alternative to activating
> always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with
> enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: I looked php:// but I was not sure how to implement it. With what you provided, I was able to resolve my problems...  Thanks ever so much.
Kelly

Comment: Just like this: `$my_data = file_get_contents('php://input');`, Then parse `$my_data` to get your variables (you indicated you could handle that part, if not then feel free to ask).

Answer (score 1):

Since POST in PHP is nothing more than an array, just iterate over it.

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
   echo($k . ': '. $v . '<br>');
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that multiple inputs with the same name will overwrite the previous one when `$_POST` is created, unless you use `bracketed[]` names, which the OP says they cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what all $_POST is sending, either var_dump($_POST) or echo print_r($_POST). This will show you all of the field names and data, even if the field names contain arrays, like your partno[].

Answer (score -1):

No way to POST 2 inputs with same name as string. You should modify the cart to convent array to string.

If you are using GET you can check out [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)() function.

Comment: it is very well possible to use a parameter name more then one time, only the way php parses the request doesn't allow you to access more then one such parameter using `$_POST`, so you have to parse the request yourself